# VB.Net Unable to change Label.text from another form with a For Loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-framework-version

I am facing a very distrubing bug that I already have worked for 6 hours. Here's the problem:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    frmProgress.Show()
    frmProgress.Label1.Text = "mmm"
    For i = 1 To 10
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        frmProgress.Label1.Text = i.ToString
        'MsgBox(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

When I click the Button1 in Form1, the text of Label1 in form frmProcess should change. This has no problem without the For loop in my code above, Label1's text will change into "mmm"(This means I have access to Label1's text property from Form1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O45vO.png)

But once the For loop was included (as well as a Do while loop, which has the same problem), **I am expecting that Label1's text increments every 0.5 sec**, but nothing works from now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaC83.png)

It only gets the i value when the loop ends:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jjd.png)

But if I add a message box to popup the i value of each step, everything works again:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhuvC.png)

I really hope that someone knows why and can help me to fix this, after 6 hours of debug, I am out of clue. Thanks for everyone who may help!

*The project is a VB.net Winform application with .net framework, IDE is Visual Studio 2019.*

Comment: The problem is that you're putting the UI thread to sleep and it's the UI thread that has to change the appearance of that `Label`. You should not be using a loop at all. You should be using a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 500 that you `Start` and then `Stop` when it has ticked as many times as you need it to. What goes in the `Tick` event handler is basically what you have in your loop, but without the `Sleep`.

Comment: If you really want to stick with the sort of thing you have, which you shouldn't, then you can call `Application.DoEvents` or the `Refresh` method of the `Label` before sleeping the UI thread, to force a repaint. The fact that calling `Application.DoEvents` is a "solution" is a good indication that what you're doing is wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your response. I am not sure if this was the problem because I actually simplified the question, initially the increment comes from a data import process, the label was used to show the percentage of a progress bar, which works. Even in this example, my progress bar works:                                        `Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
frmProgress.lblPercentage.Text = i.ToString
frmProgress.ProgressBar1.Value = i * 10` BUT! the Refresh method does HELP!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: What you're doing is a rather dodgy way to show progress. I would suggest something like [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).

Answer (score 0):

Winforms is an event driven platform, including the window drawing.  And while you put the current (ui) thread to sleep, when the thread returns, you don’t give it a chance to do anything else, including update the UI.

Popup windows work, because they have their own processing that allows updating their window before it is dismissed.

For a progress/notification, you need a background worker, which will have a callback function which is where you will make your screen update.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation for the mechanism, it is clear now!